# Paginação com grande quantidade de dados

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, desempenho, otimização

**Pensando em desempenho, qual a melhor maneira de paginar uma grande quantidade de dados?**

Atualmente estou usando um `List<Produtos>`, guardando em torno de 500 produtos nela, e utilizando `subList(min,max)`, retorna o que preciso. Porem, creio que essa não sejá a melhor solução e gostaria de saber outras alternativas para esse problema.

**Edit**

A ideia é maximizar o desempenho entre consultas desnecessarias no banco, pois o pool maximo do banco é 4.

Comment: Você usa hibernate? Ou os dados não estão em um bd?

Comment: Sim, estou usando hibernate.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `setFirstResult` e `setMaxResults`. http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination

Comment: A lista de objetos é resultado de algum filtro? Ex:  usuário só quer produtos femininos. Você está usando SQL nativo ou HQL?

Comment: Não, é resultado de um SQL em uma tabela, no caso select *.

Comment: @adelmo00 Na primeira tela não, apenas um where buscando por empresa. Posteriormente caso o cliente clique, é realizado um filtro.

Comment: @Matheus vou formular uma resposta e posto mais tarde, vai demorar um pouco

Comment: Dê mais contexto, o que você está fazendo exatamente? algo como estar buscando 500 produtos mas sempre exibe apenas 50 deles na página? se seu banco tiver mais que 500 produtos o seu código já falha porque não consegue exibir os >=501?

Comment: @BrunoRB Por se tratar de uma paginação, obviamente não será exibidos todos ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tive esse problema, resolvi com a dica da *algaworks*:

```
public List<Produto> filtrados(FiltroProduto filtro) {
    Criteria criteria = criarCriteriaParaFiltro(filtro);

    criteria.setFirstResult(filtro.getPrimeiroRegistro());
    criteria.setMaxResults(filtro.getQuantidadeRegistros());

    if (filtro.isAscendente() && filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao() != null) {
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao()));
    } else if (filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao() != null) {
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao()));
    }

    return criteria.list();
}
```

É claro que pode-se melhorar o filtro.

https://github.com/algaworks/aula-datatable-lazy-loading-primefaces

Comment: Tiago, o que me traz em desempenho usar criteria ao invés de carregar todos os produtos em uma lista? Essa é a questão. Como fazer uma paginação já foi respondido em outros comentarios.

Comment: @Matheus O que seria mais vantajoso, fazer uma consulta de 80000 itens e armazenar em uma lista ou implementar a paginação direto na query? Imagine todos esses itens sendo armazenados em um array, e agora imagine uma consulta que sempre retorna a quantidade de itens que você precisa. Ex: 20 a 20.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Não sei oq seria melhor, 20 clientes acessando um array que já tem os produtos carregados, ou os 20 clientes consultando o banco toda hora, sendo que apenas 4 cliente podem acessar o banco p/vez.

Comment: @Matheus O ponto não é o *Criteria* mas sim o fato de setar a query para retornar apenas uma certa quantidade de registros, a partir de uma certa linha (*firstResult* e *maxResults*). A resposta usa *Criteria* porque ela tinha que usar algum método (você não mostrou seu código, qual técnica de consulta está usando, então qualquer técnica de acesso a dados deve servir). Se você precisa de uma resposta mais próxima do seu código atual, mostre o seu código atual e dê mais detalhes da sua implementação.

Comment: @Matheus ai você que terá que analisar, quantas vezes vc irá carregar esse array? 
Qual o volume de dados?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Atualmente eu carrego esse array quando o primeiro cliente acessa a home do sistema. Outros clientes apenas consultam o array já carregado em uma forma de cache. O que eu não entendi é se a melhor forma é carregar tudo ou cada cliente buscar no banco a pagina que precisa, supondo que cada pagina contem 20 produtos.

Comment: Tá entendi, e depois que esse primeiro cliente entra na home os dados do banco não são modificados, ou seja, não tem nenhuma inclusão?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Não, a inclusão de novos produtos é gerenciado de outra forma, onde quando é atualizado a base, é bloqueado o acesso ao sistema. Então enquando o sistema ta liberado, os produtos não são modificados.

Comment: @Matheus então é isso que tu tem que analisar, a primeira carga da lista sempre irá demorar um tempo a mais e também creio que vai exigir um pouco mais da `VM`. Se você fizer a paginação direto no banco vc poupa um pouco de memória e também ganha performance na primeira consulta. Eu necessariamente faria paginação direto no banco, pois dessa forma eu não precisaria fazer uma carga "inútil" pois só mostraria o necessário para o cliente

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Ok, Obrigado pelas responstas.

Comment: @Matheus Por nada, boa sorte :)

Comment: @Matheus a edição foi rejeitada, pois a edição não pode acrescentar nada na resposta, que o autor não tenha adicionando anteriormente.